# Python - Random Forest - Как итеративно добавлять деревья

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Добрый день!
Я делаю задание по машинному обучению. Требуется построить RandomForest и нарисовать график зависимости качества на обучающей и тестовой выборках от количества деревьев в RandomForest. Нужно ли каждый раз для разного количества деревьев строить новый лес или можно как-то итеративно к уже имеющемуся добавлять новое дерево? Если можно, то приведите, пожалуйста, код на Python, который показывает, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

А если зайти с другой стороны?
Сначала обучить много деревьев, а потом построить график?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse

def get_mse_list(X, y, clf):
    predictions = list()
    mses = list()
    for i, tree in enumerate(clf.estimators_):
        predictions.append(tree.predict(X))
        rf_prediction = np.mean(predictions, axis=0)
        mses.append(mse(y, rf_prediction))
    return mses
```